# Mergesort Algorithm Using n/2 Extra Memory Space

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Mergesort algorithm uses **n**(size of input) extra memory space. I would like to know whether it is possible to reduce extra memory space from **n** to **n/2**.

Comment: Read the Variants section from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are at a recursive call for the range `[left, right]`, then place the first half of this range into temporary storage, and store the merge results in this range directly. For example, if our `[left, right]` range contained:

```
[left, right] = 1 4 8 2 5 9
```

We make `temp = [1 4 8]`

And start merging the second half of `[left, right]` with `temp` and overwriting `[left, right]`.